# does calling useDispatch hook cause forced re-renders on calling components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, immer.js

we can use Immer to write better reducer while still maintain immutability https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2020/06/better-reducers-with-immer/

below is the code, `ComponentA` invoke the `dispatch()` call and `ComponentB` uses `useSelector` to access the state and display it

```
const ComponentA = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  return (
    <div>
      <ComponentB />
      <button onClick={() => dispatch({ type: "Add", payload: { id: 4, name: "table" } })}>Add Product</button>
    </div>
  );
}

const ComponentB = () => {
  const products = useSelector(state => state.products); // state.products is an array [{ id, name}, ...]
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{products.reduce((a, b) => a + " " + b.name, "")}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

and the reducer is

```
import { produce } from "immer";

export const initialData = {
   products: [
      { id: 1, name: "Shoes" }, ...],
   suppliers: [
      { id: 1, name: "Zoom Shoes" },...]
}

const reducer = produce((draft = initialData, action) => {
   switch (action.type) {
      case "Add":
         draft.products.push(action.payload);
         break;
      default: 
      break;     
   }
   return draft;
});
```

My understanding in Immer is: Immer is copy-on-write, if you have 3 items in an array  `draft =  [{name: "shoe" }, {name: "hat"}, {name: "gloves"}]`, and if you modify the second item as `draft[1].name = "shirt"`, Immer will create a new obejct for the second item while the first and third item remain the same, same as the array itself.

So I expect the page won't update to display new item when clicking the button even though state is changed `ComponentB` is listening on the change on `state.products`.I know it sounds strange, but according to the React Redux official guide:

> When an action is dispatched, useSelector() will do a **reference comparison** of the previous selector result value and the current result value. If they are different, the component will be forced to re-render. If they are the same, the component will not re-render. useSelector() uses strict === reference equality checks by default, not shallow equality

so if the reference of array `state.products` is still the same (no new array instance created), then `useSelector` in `ComponentB` should think there is no change on the `state.products`, so it won't rerender.

But when I run the app I found both of `ComponentA` and `ComponentB` are re-rendered, why `ComponentA` was re-rendered? I don't think calling `useDispatch()` cause re-renders. So the re-render of `ComponentA` can only be from one of these condition below:

a. Calling `useDispatch()` automatically trigger a re-render on the calling component

b. Immer create a new array when a new item appended to it

I don't think it is b, because if Immer create a new array, componentA should not be re-rendered.

Comment: It's React, so if you are updating an element in an array, the entire array will ***necessarily*** need to be a new reference, but all the other elements that ***are not*** updated will be shallow copied to the new array. As for the component rerendering, how exactly are you determining when the component renders are happening? I don't believe `useDispatch` itself triggers a component render, but anything happening above the component can trigger React to rerender the component.

Comment: @DrewReese the only component above ComponentA is App component which just return ComponentA, you can try it on your local

Comment: Yeah, I'm not seeing both components rerender when component A dispatches that add action. I see only component B rerender, as expected. How exactly are you determining that component A is rerendering in your code?

Answer (score 0):

> Does calling `useDispatch` hook cause forced re-renders on calling
> components?

No. This is trivially testable.

Given the code for components A and B:

```js
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
```

```
const ComponentA = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("component A render");
  });
  return (
    <div>
      <ComponentB />
      <button
        onClick={() =>
          dispatch({ type: "Add", payload: { id: 4, name: "table" } })
        }
      >
        Add Product
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

```
const ComponentB = () => {
  const products = useSelector((state) => state.products);
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("component B render");
  });
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{products.map(({ name }) => name).join(" ")}</h1>
    </div>
  );
};
```

App:

```js
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ComponentA />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Reducer/store:

```js
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { produce } from "immer";

const initialData = {
  products: [{ id: 1, name: "Shoes" }],
  suppliers: [{ id: 1, name: "Zoom Shoes" }]
};

const reducer = produce((draft = initialData, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "Add":
      draft.products.push(action.payload);
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }
  return draft;
});

const store = configureStore({
  reducer
});
```

```
import { StrictMode } from "react";
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import App from "./App";

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
const root = createRoot(rootElement);

root.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
    </Provider>
  </StrictMode>
);
```

This is the output when running the app and pressing the "Add Product" three times:

[image]

The first two A and B renders are the initial render and the remount render the `React.StrictMode` component does. Following that are the three expected B-only console logs from only component B being rerendered.

### Demo Code

[image: Edit does-calling-usedispatch-hook-cause-forced-re-renders-on-calling-components]